# Internet Through VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn

I will be moving to SE Asia soon and would like to create a VPN tunnel to the US.  In the US I will maintain an AT&T gigabit fiber connection to my house.  My (naive?) thought was to use 2 [linksys vpn routers](https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-LRT214/) and configure them for [site-to-site vpn](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=143786).

My desire is to route smart TVs/streaming devices to the internet from SE Asia through the VPN tunnel to to U.S.A. and access e.g. Netflix, Amazon, HBO.

[image]

Conceptually it seems simple to me, but I am an extreme novice with network engineering.  The one thing I'm not sure about is getting internet-bound traffic from SE Asia from the Linksys VPN LRT214 in U.S.A. to the internet.  Will that require any custom routing, or will the device naturally route traffic back out the WAN to its gateway (the AT&T modem)?

Comment: Nothing magic here, it will work like you expect it to, provided the VPN routers are set up correctly. You don’t need special routers if you’re willing to use DD-WRT or OpenWrt, by the way. The bigger concern is bandwidth and latency. Does your current AT&T internet connection offer enough *upstream* bandwidth to accommodate the applications you want to use?

Comment: Yeah it’s gigabit down and up (awesome, right?) how do I route internet bound traffic through the vpn tunnel, so it doesn’t hit the local gateway and go to the internet?